# attr_accessor for class question

Tags: ruby, class-variables

I thought it was possible to define attr_accessor methods in a eigenclass like this:

```
class IOS
  @@modules_paths = "hello"

  class << self
    attr_accessor :modules_paths
  end

end

puts IOS::modules_paths
```

But this returns nothing.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `attr_accessor` you add to the class uses class-level instance variables, not class variables. This can actually be more helpful in some cases, since class variables can get ridiculous when inheritance enters the picture.

```
class IOS
  @modules_paths = "hello"

  class << self
    attr_accessor :modules_paths
  end
end

puts IOS::modules_paths # outputs "hello"
```

If you really need it to use class variables, you can define the methods manually, pull in ActiveSupport and use `cattr_accessor`, or just [copy the relevant ActiveSupport methods](http://apidock.com/rails/Class/cattr_accessor).

Answer (score 1):

You never call the `IOS::modules_paths=` setter method, nor do you assign to the corresponding `@modules_paths` instance variable anywhere. Therefore, `@modules_paths` is unitialized and thus `IOS.modules_paths` returns an unitialized variable. In Ruby, uninitialized variables evaluate to `nil` and `puts nil` prints nothing.